# How to show multiple detail in single section in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, header

I am working on crystal reports and I am stuck here with one problem. I am showing results for  IDs and they are working like:

```
ID        Name         Date              Comments
1         A           '2012-01-01'      Comments 1 on the date
1         A           '2012-01-01'      Comments 2 on the same date
```

Now if I want to show data like:

```
Details of the ABC Company
...............................................................................
ID        Name         Date              Comments
1          A          '2012-01-01'       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                         bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                                         ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

Details of DEF company
...............................................................................
ID        Name         Date              Comments
2          B          '2013-01-11'       rciwtyiabtbtaerynct
                                         hubytnituinmyuimyumiy
                                         jk jk jk jk jk jk jk uir
```

How to achieve that? I am least interested in creating a subreport for the sections below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your main concern is only the Header section which says 'Details of the ABC Company' etc etc.For that you may use GroupExpert(RightClick on Report-->Insert-->Group) and you may group it with your Details company header section

for grouping you may refer [Grouping 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ea36c5/crystal-reports-grouping-pattern-1/)

and here [Grouping 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula that would be the combination of ID, name and Date.
Then  group on that formula

if it is okay to have a different line, then simply put the fields ID, name and Date and group at teh group level and comment at the detail level

if it is not okay to have a different line, then put hte fields ID, name, Date and comment to the detail line and do a suppress formula so that they are only showed on the first element of the group (formula to be find out)

Answer (score 0):

In your crystal report right click the details section and select insert section below,now u have two details sections a and b.u can add mulitple details section and page header also.